# Proof that the median of two subsets is the upper and lower bound of the median of the combined set

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

I have median of two subsets, and want to know if I can infer anything about the median of the overall set.  Intuitively, it feels like the median of these two subsets form a range of possible values of the median of the larger set, but I don't know how to go about proving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define the two subsets as A and B and decide to call A the one with the lower median, x, and let the median of B = y.  That means that 50 percent of the data in the A subset is lower than x and 50 percent of the B data are lower than y.  When we combine the two data sets, (no matter how large each set is), the 50 percent of A and B will become lower percentages of the combined data set.

Since 50 percent of the A set contained values less than x, and some fraction LESS than 50 percent of set B contained values less than x (because the median of B = y>x), any weighted combination of the two data sets will have a median that must be greater than (or equal to) x (i.e., less than 50 percent of the combined data set will be less than x).

We can use the same logic to show that the median of the combined data set must also be less than (or equal to) y.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thank you